# MDX filter member in where clause vs filter member in From clause

Tags: mdx, where-clause, subquery

IN ADVENTURE WORKS what is difefrence between this two situations:

1) filter member in From Clause:

```
with
member [existing_categries_Member_Count]as
    count(existing[Product].[Category].[Category].members)
member [existing_subcategries_Member_Count]as
    count(existing[Product].[subCategory].[subCategory].members)
select 
{
    [existing_subcategries_Member_Count],
    [existing_categries_Member_Count]
} on 0
FROM (
    SELECT [Product].[Subcategory].&[31] ON 0
    FROM [Adventure Works])
```

---

Results:

```
existing_subcategries_Member_Count  existing_categries_Member_Count
                    37                            4
```

AND 
2) Filter Member In WHERE Clause:

```
with
member [existing_categries_Member_Count]as
    count(existing[Product].[Category].[Category].members)
member [existing_subcategries_Member_Count]as
    count(existing[Product].[subCategory].[subCategory].members)
select 
{
    [existing_subcategries_Member_Count],
    [existing_categries_Member_Count]
} on 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Product].[Subcategory].&[31]
```

---

Results :

```
existing_subcategries_Member_Count  existing_categries_Member_Count
                   1                              1
```

I expect the same results for the two queries but I see diffrent results.
Please tell me the difference between WHERE AND SUbcube
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you put a member in a WHERE clause, you override the default member (the context is changed).
- After the [subselect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145541.aspx) is evaluated the current member on `[Product].[Subcategory]` is still `[Product].[Subcategory].[All Products]`

As you used the [existing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145541.aspx) keyword in your calculated members, you can not have the same results. If you remove it, your 2 queries will give the same result.